# How to automate login to Oracle Access Manager console through java Code

Tags: oracle

I want java code to automate the entire login process to oamconsole in Oracle Access Manager.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAM login console is nothing but a webpage and you could automate using Selenium webdriver scripts.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Login {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
               WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://");
            WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
            WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
            WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("Submit"));

            id.sendKeys("admin");
            pass.sendKeys("password");
            button.click();


     }

}
```

Comment: Hello,When I am running the above code,its simply showing no output at all.How shall i print responses to debug?